# Preview photos directly on laptop?

Tags: workflow, preview, nikon-d40

I'm going to help a friend taking a large number of product images and I'm wondering how I can easily preview the images on a computer screen without removing the card in my camera? I will be using a Nikon D40 for taking the images and preferable looking for a product that can transfer the images wireless. Is this possible somehow?

Comment: Can't speak for the D40 but almost all DSLRs support tethered shooting with a USB cable using a variety of software, including LightRoom

Comment: yes, D40 would allow this.. but not exactly wireless ;)

Comment: Thanks. Although not wireless, tt's still a good tip for me because I didn't know it could be tethered that way.

Comment: I checked this out and it seems to require some expensive software from Nikon?

Comment: You can use the Nikon software, or if you already use/have Adobe Lr3 then this has tethered shooting support built right into it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about using an [Eye-Fi](http://www.eye.fi/) wireless SD card?

Comment: Eye-Fi is a very good option but not all cameras support it.

Comment: According to their webpage Nikon D40 is supported.

Comment: Great tip! I suppose it's possible to get it to do automatic sync with a folder on my machine to get some poor man tethering with e.g. Picasa?