# Are there any cameras which transfer photos to PC without interaction

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I want to buy a secondary compact camera which is able to transfer photos immediately to my PC via WiFi/Bluetooth/anything.

Don't want to go through pressing 10 buttons to get 1 photo on PC. Just shot - and JPG is in a network shared drive.

Are there any options?

Comment: Similar question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/4011/preview-photos-directly-on-laptop/4015#4015

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Basically, you just want to make sure that it supports [Eye-Fi SD cards](http://www.eye.fi/).  As long as it does, then the memory card will take care of the upload.

Comment: Once the pictures are transfer to computer, does it get automatically deleted from the Eyefi card? thanks.

Comment: @rvpals It could be configured to be deleted. Extremely unfortunately EyeFi is almost dead...